# nested loops for json printing

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

i'm trying to print LineRef of this python object which is made by using jason.loads.

```
{
    "Siri": {
        "ServiceDelivery": {
            "ResponseTimestamp": "2014-08-09T12:07:08.519-04:00",
            "VehicleMonitoringDelivery": [
                {
                    "VehicleActivity": [
                        {
                            "MonitoredVehicleJourney": {
                                "LineRef": "MTA NYCT_B38",
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

so far I have written this code:

```
theJSON = json.loads(data)
for j in theJSON["VehicleMonitoringDelivery"]:
    for i in theJSON["VehicleActivity"]:
        print  [i]["MonitoredVehicleJourney"]["LineRef"]
```

but it gives error at the JSON

Comment: "gives error at the JSON" is not informative. What error? We are not mind readers.

Comment: if you are using `python 3` `print  [i]["MonitoredVehicleJourney"]["LineRef"]` will def give you an error

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: it'll give an error in Python 2 just as much.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I was referring to the lack of parens

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I know, and I am referring to the `[i]` syntax.

Comment: which library to add to use function isDigit in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot directly address the `VehicleMonitoringDelivery` key, it is nested in the `ServiceDelivery` nested in the `Siri` dictionary:

```
theJSON = json.loads(data)
for delivery in theJSON['Siri']['ServiceDelivery']['VehicleMonitoringDelivery']:
    for activity in delivery['VehicleActivity']:
        print activity['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['LineRef']
```

or using indexing to get the first (can fail if the lists are empty:

```
theJSON = json.loads(data)
try:
    delivery = theJSON['Siri']['ServiceDelivery']['VehicleMonitoringDelivery'][0]
    activity = delivery['VehicleActivity'][0]
except IndexError:
    print 'None-such'
else:
    print activity['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['LineRef']
```

Demo:

```
>>> theJSON = {
...     "Siri": {
...         "ServiceDelivery": {
...             "ResponseTimestamp": "2014-08-09T12:07:08.519-04:00",
...             "VehicleMonitoringDelivery": [
...                 {
...                     "VehicleActivity": [
...                         {
...                             "MonitoredVehicleJourney": {
...                                 "LineRef": "MTA NYCT_B38",
...                             }
...                         }
...                     ]
...                 }
...             ]
...         }
...     }
... }
>>> for delivery in theJSON['Siri']['ServiceDelivery']['VehicleMonitoringDelivery']:
...     for activity in delivery['VehicleActivity']:
...         print activity['MonitoredVehicleJourney']['LineRef']
... 
MTA NYCT_B38
```

Comment: @user3296651: Did you forget to include the `theJSON` assignment perhaps?

Comment: when i write print theJson then all output comes

Comment: its getting printed now, howwever the result is coming multiple times. 
where as i just need it print out just once

Comment: @user3296651: then use `break` in the loop or use indexing into the lists.

Comment: can you please help me how, I am new to python and json